# Fast way to convert a polygon shapefile to a raster in R

Tags: r, rstats

I have a polygon shapefile and I would like to know how to convert it to a raster, with a new column (variable), like height which is always 1 (constant value).

And the fast way, may be with Terra package?

Comment: Sure, you can use the `terra` package for that (https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/rasterize.html), or the `fasterize` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasterize/fasterize.pdf). I have never used the latter but if you are curious it would be nice to compare their performances (`terra` vs `fasterize`) and post the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the example from `terra` `help("rasterize")` but with a finer grid:

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
r <- rast(v, ncols=750, nrows=1000)
z <- rasterize(v, r)
plot(z)
```

Produces a raster of NA and 1, even though the spatial data is made of several sub-regions. You can burn in attribute values if you want.

[image]

Currently `fasterize` only works on the older `raster` data (unless its been updated recently...) but I can convert from `terra` and use `sf` polygons:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(fasterize)
sv = st_read(f)
rv = raster(r)
fz = fasterize(sv, rv)
plot(fz)
```

[image]

It looks a bit different because the `raster` grids have a different plotting method, but the underlying data is identical.

You can benchmark:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(fasterize(sv, rv), rasterize(v, r))
Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
 fasterize(sv, rv)  2.728527  2.884772  5.402486  3.020942  4.599591 164.8493
   rasterize(v, r) 11.678077 12.450645 14.321236 13.425334 14.801525  71.2856
```

and `fasterize` is clearly faster but you will have to drop to `raster` objects to work with it.